# How to switch between pages in customtkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, encoding, pycharm

Need help with switching pages in customtkinter because i changed some of the codes i got from online websites.

Tried copying codes posted by others but the screen went blank, im expecting a new page to appear after i click an image

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.